# Spring Mqtt integration - type mismatch in Kotlin while the same types work in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-integration

I'm relatively new to Kotlin. Currently I'm working on a spring boot (v 3.0.5) application that also uses MQTT via the spring-integration-mqtt lib (v 6.0.4). So fare everything works fine I can send and receive messages via MQTTS. Now I need handle messages to-and-from more topics and wanted to configure a shared client for this, as explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html#mqtt-shared-client

However, when I transfer that exact example to Kotlin

```kotlin
@Bean
fun clientManager(): ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectOptions> {
    val connectionOptions = MqttConnectionOptions()
    connectionOptions.serverURIs = arrayOf(brokerUrl)
    connectionOptions.userName = username
    connectionOptions.password = password.toByteArray()
    connectionOptions.connectionTimeout = 30000;
    connectionOptions.maxReconnectDelay = 1000;
    connectionOptions.isAutomaticReconnect = true;

    val clientManager = Mqttv5ClientManager(connectionOptions, clientId)
    clientManager.setPersistence(MqttDefaultFilePersistence())
    return clientManager
}
```

I get the following error:

```bash
Type mismatch: inferred type is Mqttv5ClientManager but ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectOptions> was expected
```

When I do the same thing in Java, as shown in the Spring documentation, then it works just fine. To me it seems that Kotlin is not able to resolve the class hierarchy for the ClientManager Interface. The [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/core/ClientManager.html) clearly indicates that Mqttv5ClientManager is a known Implementation for ClientManager.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with a `MqttConnectOptions` which is essentially this class:

```
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions
```

for MQTT v5 it has to be this:

```
org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttConnectionOptions
```

Therefore your bean definition must be like this:

```
fun clientManager(): ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> {
```

See `Mqttv5ClientManager` class source code.

Comment: Thank you for the catch with the ConnectOptions vs ConnectionOptions. You are right with the signature. I changed my code and then also found that I had the wrong IMqttAsyncClient imported. Because I used the same class to experiment with MQTT v3 connections before.